# Random Forest : finding relevant features

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to train a RF model in sklearn for classification. The accuracy I get for the test is quite low with a specified set of feature vector. I assume that the feature vector I chose is misleading the model. So I tried RFE, RFECV etc to find a relevant set of feature vector - didn't help to improve the accuracy. I came up with a simple feature selection process as below>

```
ml_feats = #initial set of feature vector

while True
    feats_to_del=[]
    prev_score=0
    for feat_len in range(2,len(ml_feats)):
        classifier = RandomForestClassifier(**init_params)
        classifier.fit(X[ml_feats[:feat_len]],Y)
        score = classifier.score(Xt[ml_feats[:feat_len]],Yt)
        if score<prev_score:
             #feature that caused the score to decrease
             print ml_feats[feat_len]
             feat_to_del.append(ml_feats[feat_len])
        prev_score=score
    if len(feats_to_del)==0:
        break
    #delete irrelevant features
    ml_feats=list(set(ml_feats)-set(feats_to_del))

print ml_feats #print all relevant features
```

Does the above code help figure out right set of features?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a greedy feature selection. If you want to use RandomForestClassifier to select features, you can do something like:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
# xtrain : training data
# ytrain : training labels

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
sfm = SelectFromModel(estimator=clf, threshold='mean') # threshold of selection is mean of feature importances by random forest classifier
sfm.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
selected_xtrain = sfm.transform(xtrain)
```

Comment: will it help removing irrelevant features?

Comment: its very difficult to say what will work without looking at the data